# Update a internet explorer window after data input

Tags: excel, vba

So i am currently running a web automation macro that loops through data.

the issue i have is, when i start the macro after it log onto the web page, info is required before the search button can be pressed.

once the info is populated, hypothetically is should allow the search button to be pressed, but it cant be pressed until i interact with the web page for some reason, so i have two screens when i click the macro to begin the second screen will show the web page and the process happening it will stop at the point where the macro has to click on the search button, the search button shows grey which means i cant press it but once i either stop the macro or click on the site it then allows me to continue to search.

this only happens for the first case and after the rest of the data will loop through without stopping the macro or having to interact with the page  by clicking it.

i have realized that send keys work , by sending enter it also bypasses the issue but they are unreliable, they require the window to be active which i have done with the hwnd and setforegroundwindow declaration but it doesn't change that i cant run this task in the background because will forever interrupt other processes this way.

is there any other work around?
thank you in advance

```
 SUB AUTOMATION()

       Dim Rng As Range
       Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim IEe As internetexplorer
        Dim doc, element
        Dim response As String

    Set IEe = New internetexplorer
    IEe.Visible = false
    IEe.Navigate “website here” 

    Do While IEe.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until IEe.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set element = IEe.Document.getElementByID("login button")
    element.Click

    Do While IEe.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until IEe.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set element = IEe.Document.getElementByID("search bar")
    element.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A13").Value
    Set element = IEe.Document.getElementByID("search button") 'IT IS HERE I CANT PROCEED
    element.Click
```

Comment: Like you said, the button is only enabled when you interact with the site. This happens quite regularly with automation. It generally is because page does not recognise the updates made by the automated process. There are tricks to get around this but please post your code so that we can see how you are interacting with the site

Comment: @Zac i have added the code

Comment: After setting `element` value (**BTW** it is strongly recommended that you don't use reserved words for variable names), try clicking on the field and then do a send ke to TAB out of it. that generally resolves the issue. Sometimes just a click on the field enables the button

Comment: @Zac i have used a send key when i made the application visible, it is unreliable and works a small amount of the time, ive also tried sending the same command with api but that doesnt make a difference, and ive also tried clicking via the code different parts of the page but it does not do anything without actual interaction which i feel maybe triggers a page update

Comment: Have a look at something called `FireEvent`. You can fire an event on the page which will force the page to validate the value in your `element` field. Once the page recognises that there is a value in the field, it should then enable the button